# How to arrange items in a list box by using radio button

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, radio-button

Ok, so i want to be able to display all the information in the list box when the radio button 'all' is clicked. I also want to be able to display the players "only" when the 'players' radio button is clicked, the same for manager's also. Any help? Thanks!

```
class Create
{
    public enum Job { Player, Manager }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Job Porm { get; set; }

    public Create(string name, int age, Job porm)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        Porm = porm;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Name: {0} - Age {1} - {2}", Name, Age, Porm);
    }
}
```

---

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ObservableCollection<Create> playersAndManagers;

        playersAndManagers = new ObservableCollection<Create>();

        Create newPlayer1 = new Create("John Terry", 27, Create.Job.Player);
        Create newManager1 = new Create("jose mourinho", 51, Create.Job.Manager);
        Create newPlayer2 = new Create("Wayne Rooney", 23, Create.Job.Player);
        Create newPlayer3 = new Create("David Beckham", 37, Create.Job.Player);
        Create newManager2 = new Create("David Moyes", 55, Create.Job.Manager);

        playersAndManagers.Add(newPlayer1);
        playersAndManagers.Add(newManager1);
        playersAndManagers.Add(newPlayer2);
        playersAndManagers.Add(newPlayer3);
        playersAndManagers.Add(newManager2);

        lbxInfo.ItemsSource = playersAndManagers;
    }
}
```

}

---

I have an image but it wont let me post it

---

Actually, here's the code for the xaml

```
<Window x:Class="example1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="lbxInfo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="207" Margin="66,71,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="368"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="rbtnAll" Content="All" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="66,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="rbtnPlayers" Content="Players" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="203,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="rbtnManagers" Content="Managers" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="352,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
```

With the radio buttons

[image]

Comment: Anyone know how to do this or link me to a website that can show me?

Comment: Have you looked into LINQ?

Comment: No, I have never, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your IObservableCollection to expose only the results you want, not all of them to begin with, so:

```
ObservableCollection<Create> results = new ObservableCollection<Create>();
lbxInfo.ItemsSource = results;
```

Then keep a collection of all items:

```
// naming variables is not my strong point...
private IList<Create> _allPlayersAndManagers = new List<Create>();
_allPlayersAndManagers.Add(new Create("John Terry", 27, Create.Job.Player);
```

Now all you have to do is populate the results when the respective button is checked, by using the Checked event of each button:

```
<RadioButton x:Name="rbtnPlayers" Content="Players" Checked="OnPlayersChecked"/>
```

Then handle it as such:

```
private void OnPlayersChecked(object source, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // must use the same observable instance as the binding uses
    // clear any existing entries
    results.Clear();

    // only care about players...
    foreach (var player in _allPlayersAndManagers.Where(c => c.Job == c.Job.Player))
    {
        results.Add(player);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this helps alot, I couldn't figure out the for each statement but now it all makes sense, thanks again!